# How should it works in Unity - slider.maxValue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I request help with `slider.maxValue = unit.maxHealth;`.
The HP bar appears above the desired object from the necessary prefab, where the slider should have a maximum value equal to the character's `maxHealth` and a current value equal to the character's Health. However, when the slider is created, it has the values ​​specified by the prefab and is not changed according to these lines:

```
slider.maxValue = unit.maxHealth;
slider.value = unit.health;
```

StatusBarController:

```
public class StatusBarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject   statusBarPrefab;
    public Transform    statusBarParent;

    private Slider      slider;
    private Image       fillImage;

    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject statusBarObject = Instantiate(statusBarPrefab, statusBarParent);
        slider = statusBarObject.GetComponentInChildren<Slider>();
        fillImage = statusBarObject.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();

        Unit unit = GetComponent<Unit>();
        slider.maxValue = unit.maxHealth;
        slider.value = unit.health;

        SetHPBarColorByTagPrefix();

        unit.OnHealthChanged += UpdateHPStatusBar;
    }
```

Unit:

```
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int                        maxHealth;
    public int                        health;
    public int                        stamina;
    public int                        mana;
    public float                      m_speed;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     getDamaged;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     isAttackingBasicAttack;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     isAttackingHeavyAttack;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     isParrying;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     isDead;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     isStunned;
    [HideInInspector] public bool     isRooted;

    public event Action               OnHealthChanged;
}
```

I can't figure out the exact location of the problem.

Comment: I also thought about the order of component implementation, but I don't think the problem is in that. Unit comes before the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the HP bar, apparently the method GetComponentInChildren() couldn't retrieve the slider component properly in the hierarchy of the HP bar prefab. I remade the prefab, placed the slider component on the top-most object in the hierarchy, and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to create a method to set your character **MaxHealth** when you instantiate.

Here is my HealthBar:

```
public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SetMaxHealth(int health)         
    {
        slider.maxValue = health;
        slider.value = health
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. I also tried to pass the values from Unit using a getters, but it was also unsuccessful.